# Which is better one-handed backhand or two-handed backhand?

Tags: tennis, technique

I've tried both backhands but i prefer one-handed backhand because of reach and disguise of dropshots and mobility,

I know one-handed backhand is dying art right now because it's hard to master rather than double-handed backhand which is easy to master and has more power in it.

Tennis Freak which would you prefer?

Comment: Where do you get the idea that the two-handed backhand "has more power to it" ? I think the difference is small but the one-hander is actually slightly more powerful because it's not inhibited by having to keep two-hands on the racquet as you unwind your core.

Comment: More power – the power of the one-handed backhand comes mostly by stepping into the ball. Rotation of the body and backswing are second in line. When hitting a two-handed backhand, power can also come from stepping into the ball (lateral force), but also from rotating the upper body around the head (angular force) to lessen the degree from the backswing. So, it is obvious that the two-hander has an edge over the one-hander. - See more at: http://www.tennismindgame.com/one-or-two-handed-backhand.html#sthash.J4T8iWf5.dpuf

Answer (score 0):

If you are just a casual player, I would say it's a matter of preference. I use a two-handed backhand for topspin and one-handed for slice, but I am old! The reason I prefer a two-handed backhand is because I save some of my right arm by leveraging my left arm (again, I am old...). I was also told that it's possible to make my backhand more powerful than my forehand that way, it's not there yet, but I am working on it!

Here's a good link with comparisons:
http://www.tennismindgame.com/one-or-two-handed-backhand.html

The article ends with the conclusion that you should use a one-handed backhand for slice, and a two-handed backhand for topspin.

Answer (score 0):

From what i know from when i used to play, the two handed backhand is more used to drive the ball down to the end of the court to push your opponent around. Or to do those smashing shots downt the line when you've just been having an across court rally.

The one handed though is used for drop shots just behind the net and to put backspin on the ball, BUT when i played in the past i could place the ball anywhere on the court within half a metre of where i was aiming. So i think that the one handed backhand is just for placement, and if your opponent is up at the net, the one-handed backhand should be the better of the two to go up over him/her.

Each backhand is obviously better than the other in different situations but i recon that if i had to play a full game only using only the two handed backhand i would have a much bigger chance of winning than with just the one handed, so i would say the two handed backhand is  better.

Hope this helped  :)